# Imported class files are shown under default package in Eclipse, how can i access them?

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I am new in Java and Eclipse.

I am trying to import external class files in my code. I right click on project src->properties->buildpath->configure build path-> libraries->add external class folder
by doing this default package appears in referenced libraries, having all the Java class files, but I still can't import my file.

Next I zip all .class files in a zip folder and add as external jars, by doing this all class files are shown under default package, under referenced libraries, and still I can't import my class files into code.

How can I rename the default package, so that I can access and import the class files?

By right clicking the classes, under the default package in the referenced libraries, there comes no option of refactor and move.

Comment: Perhaps you can try to explain your problem in a way one can understand what you are doing. Using punctuation may also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to respect the File System Hierarchy in which the class files come from.

Let's assume that the class files (For example the class Clazz) have the declaration `package ch.charno.xy`, they must remain in a folder hierarchy `ch/charno/xy/Clazz.class`. You have to import the folder in which the subfolder `ch` resides so that the correct hierarchy is preserved. It's not possible to just import the class files, but you need to import the whole folder hierarchy.

(I hope I understood your question)

Comment: thankyou sir, i got your point, and it worked. thanks alot!! :)